# Variable 'result' must be initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I INITIALLY INITIALIZED RESULT IN THE BEGINNING OF THE OVERRIDE FUN doInBackground()
but during the return result it is showing that (Variable 'result' must be initialized)
in the android studio its showing underline red mark under the return result.
this code in in kotlin
i am writing this because stack overflow showing this to me

here is the code

```
package shubham.lists.simpleapicalldemo

import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.AsyncTask
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.lang.StringBuilder
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException
import java.net.URL
import java.sql.Connection

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        CallAPILoginAsyncTask()
    }

    private inner class CallAPILoginAsyncTask(): AsyncTask<Any, Void, String>() {
        private lateinit var customProgressDialog:Dialog

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            showProgressDialog()
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Any?): String? {
            var result:String
            var connection:HttpURLConnection?=null
            try{
                val url=URL("https://run.mocky.io/v3/60440f20-9025-4fa5-84b6-e7f801ad8d14")
                connection=url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                connection.doInput=true
                connection.doOutput=true
                val httpResult:Int=connection.responseCode
                if(httpResult==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    val inputStream=connection.inputStream
                    val reader=BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
                    val stringBuilder=StringBuilder()
                    var line:String?
                    try {
                        while(reader.readLine().also { line=it }!=null){
                            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n")
                        }
                    } catch (e:IOException){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    finally {
                        try{
                            inputStream.close()
                        } catch (e:IOException){
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                    }
                    result=stringBuilder.toString()
                }
                else{
                    connection.responseMessage
                }
            }
            catch (e:SocketTimeoutException){
                result="Connection timed out"
            }
            catch (e:Exception){
                result="Error "+ e.message
            }
            finally {
                connection?.disconnect()
            }
            return result
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            cancelProgressDialog()
            Log.i("JSON RESPONSE RESULT",result!!)
        }

        private fun showProgressDialog(){
            customProgressDialog=Dialog(this@MainActivity)
            customProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom_progress)
            customProgressDialog.show()
        }
        private fun cancelProgressDialog(){
            customProgressDialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

WAITING FOR AN EARLY RESPONSE

Answer (score 1):

You're not initialising it at the start - you're *declaring* the variable and its type, but you're not setting an initial *value* on it.

```
var result:String
```

That's fine inside functions *so long as you set a value on it before you try to read it* (similar to `lateinit` on top-level variables), but here's what your code's logic is - I've stripped out most of it so you can see the important stuff:

```
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Any?): String? {
            var result:String
            try{
                if(httpResult==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    result=stringBuilder.toString()
                }
                else{
                    connection.responseMessage
                }
            }
            catch (e:SocketTimeoutException){
                result="Connection timed out"
            }
            catch (e:Exception){
                result="Error "+ e.message
            }
            return result
        }
```

You only set `result` if your `try` block throws an exception, or if you get a `HTTP_OK` response - otherwise you hit that `else` block, then go straight to the `return` statement without setting a value for `result`. I'm guessing you meant `result = connection.responseMessage` in the `else`?